# boost date missing template arguments before

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I'm getting a `missing template arguments` when compiling a simple date parsing test using boost, here is the code:

```
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/parsers.hpp"

boost::date_time::date test = boost::gregorian::from_us_string("07-Sep-2010");
```

and the compiler complains
`error: missing template arguments before ‘test’
  boost::date_time::date test = boost::gregorian::from_us_string("07-Sep-2010");`

I don't understand what template arguments I should provide or why I should do provide template arguments in first place. It seems to be a little to much boiler plate code for my taste:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be [`boost::gregorian::date`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_class) instead of `boost::date_time::date`.
Aside from that, you could use

```
auto test = boost::gregorian::from_us_string("07-Sep-2010");
```

if you are using C++11.